# IPYTHON:Stop execution of the current operation without exiting ipython

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, tmux

Sometimes (not always) ctrl-C quits me out of ipython session, instead of just stopping execution of the current task. You can 
imagine how infuriating it is to hit ctrl-C and loose all my work.

Is there any workaround?

I am using ubuntu. IPython 1.2.1 And I am also using tmux.